# spark scala: remove consecutive (by date) duplicates records from a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, duplicates

The question is regarding working with dataframes, I want to delete completely duplicate records excluding some fields (dates).
I tried to use a windowFunction (WindowSpec) as:

```
val wFromDupl: WindowSpec = Window
  .partitionBy(comparateFields: _*)
  .orderBy(asc(orderField))
```

At the variable comparateFields I store all the fields that I have to check (in the example it would be DESC1 and DESC2) to eliminate duplicates following the logic that, if there is a duplicate record, we discard those with higher date.

In the orderField variable, I simply store the effective_date field.

Therefore, by applying the window function, what I do is calculate a temporary column, assigning the smallest date to all the records that are duplicates, and then filter the dataFrame as:

```
 val dfFinal: DataFrame = dfInicial
    .withColumn("w_eff_date", min(col("effective_date")).over(wFromDupl))
  .filter(col("effective_date") === col("w_eff_date")) 
  .drop("w_eff_date")
  .distinct()
  .withColumn("effective_end_date", lead(orderField, 1, "9999-12-31").over(w))
```

For the following case it works correctly:

```
KEY EFFECTIVE_DATE  DESC 1  DESC 2  W_EFF_DATE (tmp)
E2  2000            A       B       2000
E2  2001            A       B       2000
E2  2002            AA      B       2002
```

The code will drop the second record:

```
E2  2001            A       B       2000
```

But the logic must be applied for CONSECUTIVE records (in date), for example, for the following case, as the code is implemented, we are deleting the third record (DESC1 and DESC2 are the same, and the min eff date is 2000), but we dont want this because we have (by eff_date) a record in the middle (2001 AA B)so we want to keep the 3 records

```
KEY EFFECTIVE_DATE  DESC1   DESC2   W_EFF_DATE (tmp)
E1     2000         A       B       2000
E1     2001         AA      B       2001
E1     2002         A       B       2000
```

Any advice on this?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use `when/otherwise` along with Window function `lag` to determine which rows to keep, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
  ("E1", "2000", "A",  "B"),
  ("E1", "2001", "AA", "B"),
  ("E1", "2002", "A",  "B"),
  ("E1", "2003", "A",  "B"),
  ("E1", "2004", "A",  "B"),
  ("E2", "2000", "C",  "D"),
  ("E2", "2001", "C",  "D"),
  ("E2", "2002", "CC", "D"),
  ("E2", "2003", "C",  "D")
).toDF("key", "effective_date", "desc1", "desc2")

val compareCols = List("desc1", "desc2")

val win1 = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("effective_date")

val df2 = df.
  withColumn("compCols", struct(compareCols.map(col): _*)).
  withColumn("rowNum", row_number.over(win1)).
  withColumn("toKeep",
    when($"rowNum" === 1 || $"compCols" =!= lag($"compCols", 1).over(win1), true).
      otherwise(false)
  )

// +---+--------------+-----+-----+--------+------+------+
// |key|effective_date|desc1|desc2|compCols|rowNum|toKeep|
// +---+--------------+-----+-----+--------+------+------+
// | E1|          2000|    A|    B|   [A,B]|     1|  true|
// | E1|          2001|   AA|    B|  [AA,B]|     2|  true|
// | E1|          2002|    A|    B|   [A,B]|     3|  true|
// | E1|          2003|    A|    B|   [A,B]|     4| false|
// | E1|          2004|    A|    B|   [A,B]|     5| false|
// | E2|          2000|    C|    D|   [C,D]|     1|  true|
// | E2|          2001|    C|    D|   [C,D]|     2| false|
// | E2|          2002|   CC|    D|  [CC,D]|     3|  true|
// | E2|          2003|    C|    D|   [C,D]|     4|  true|
// +---+--------------+-----+-----+--------+------+------+

df2.where($"toKeep").select(df.columns.map(col): _*).
  show
// +---+--------------+-----+-----+
// |key|effective_date|desc1|desc2|
// +---+--------------+-----+-----+
// | E1|          2000|    A|    B|
// | E1|          2001|   AA|    B|
// | E1|          2002|    A|    B|
// | E2|          2000|    C|    D|
// | E2|          2002|   CC|    D|
// | E2|          2003|    C|    D|
// +---+--------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much LeoC, it is a simple and good solution, it has worked properly with half a million records in my local env. The only change I had to make, is because the struct field went out of range (with my real data). But I solved it with an array:

Comment: Glad that you're able to derive a solution out of it to address specific needs.